# What is the meaning of "minimal key"?

Tags: primary-key, relational-theory, terminology, candidate-key

In the definition, it says *minimal key* is a minimal set of attributes needed to identify the table. Does the "minimal" part mean "minimal number of attributes" or "cannot be eliminated"?

For example:

- For a relation `R(A, B, C, D, E, F)`, the closure of `A`, `BC`, and `DEF` are all `{A, B, C, D, E, F}`.

Are they all minimal keys? Or is only `A` the minimal key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all minimal keys.

Minimal means there is no proper subset with the same property.